Ethereum Smart Contract Testing with Hardhat, ethers.js, Mocha -- Bug: "ReferenceError: window is not defined"
I'm following this (https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts) tutorial on smart contract testing. Here is the test I've written:
const { expect } = require("chai"); 
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { loadFixture } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox/network-helpers");


describe("NFT Contract", function () {

  async function deployTokenFixture() {

    const [owner, creator, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const argsarray  = [
      '530',
      '13',
      '40',
      creator.address,
      addr1.address,
      "ipfs://bafybeifvxxvebdaxpae6gcrudsn7w6vnrhu5c3d6lworiqrkiowano4ayu/2.json",
    ];

    const hardhatToken = await ethers.deployContract("testNFT", constructorArgs = argsarray, signer=owner,);

    await hardhatToken.waitForDeployment();

    return { hardhatToken, owner, creator, addr1, addr2 };
  }

  describe("Contract Owner", function () {
    it("Deployment should set owner to owner", async function () {

      const [owner] = await loadFixture(deployTokenFixture);

      expect(await hardhatToken.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
    });

  });

});


When I run npx hardhat test I get the error mentioned in the title. Here it is in full:
(base) user1@user test % npx hardhat test
An unexpected error occurred:

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user1/Workspaces/NFT-Smart-Contract/test/coverage/lcov-report/prettify.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at /Users/user1/Workspaces/NFT-Smart-Contract/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:414:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/user1/Workspaces/NFT-Smart-Contract/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:411:14)

Does anyone have any insight into how to fix this? I think it is expecting to operate in browser, but I'm unsure. If it is, is there a work-around?
I've tried installing jsdom, but the dependencies cannot be resolved and --legacy-peer-deps doesn't solve the issue.
